# FTP Client reply sync

Tags: c#

I'm writting a FTP client in C# with a socket.
Now I have the following problem. When I send a FTP command through my control connection socket to the Server I try to receive the reply. But sometimes the server sends the data with delays.
My result are fragmented.

Now my code:

```
public byte[] BinaryReceive()
{
       byte[] bytes;
       using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
             {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4056];
                        while (_controlConnectionSocket.Available > 0)
                        {
                            int count = _controlConnectionSocket.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);

                            Thread.Sleep(100);
                        }
                        bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

              }
       return bytes;
 }
```

How can I avoid this situation? Currenty I implemented the `Thread.Sleep()` a as workaround. But this can not be the solution.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

I solved the problem. The key is, not to use `Available > 0` instead I wait for the reply end. Than it works..

Comment: If you don't have Thread.Sleep(100) does the connection timeout?

Comment: No. The data is little later available. My next receive contains the message of the last command..